# Auto-Confirmation Emails not sending using trigger "on form submit"

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I just created a new Google form and want an automatic confirmation email to go out when the form is submitted. Essentially, an academic department uses the form to approve or deny transfer credit for a student, and then the automatic email confirmation goes to the student, so that he/she knows the decision without having to contact the student separately.

I did this before with 2 different forms about 5 months ago and never had a problem. But with this new form that I just created, the emails are not working. It appeared to be working yesterday, but I can't recreate the successful email confirmation today.  I've looked through the message boards, but haven't found the same exact issue.

I'm using the script editor and creating a trigger "on form submit."  I started with the code that I know works for my other form and just changed the values and the message. My script looks like this:

```
function myFunction(e) {

  var UserName = e.values[1];  
  var LastName = e.values[2];  
  var FirstName = e.values[3];  
  var SAGEID = e.values[4];  
  var UserEmail = e.values[5];  
  var Dept = e.values[6];  
  var Coll1 = e.values[11];  
  var Course1 = e.values[12];  
  var Req1 = e.values[13];  
  var Decision1 = e.values[14];  
  var Coll2 = e.values[15];  
  var Course2 = e.values[16];  
  var Req2 = e.values[17];  
  var Decision2 = e.values[18];  
  var Coll3 = e.values[19]  
  var Course3 = e.values[20];  
  var Req3 = e.values[21];  
  var Decision3 = e.values[22];  
  var Coll4 = e.values[23];  
  var Course4 = e.values[24];  
  var Req4 = e.values[25];  
  var Decision4 = e.values[26];  
  var Notes = e.values[9];  

  var Subject = "Course Equivalency Request Decision - " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " (" + Dept + ")";  
  var Message = "The " + Dept + " department has made a decision regarding your course equivalency request. Any questions regarding the decision below should be directed to the " + Dept + " department. " +  

 "\n\n\nDepartment Comments: " + Notes + 
 "\n\nCourse 1: " + Coll1 + ": " + Course1 + "\nDecision: " + Decision1 +    "\nRequirement: " + Req1 +  
 "\n\nCourse 2: " + Coll2 + ": " + Course2 + "\nDecision: " + Decision2 + 
 "\nRequirement: " + Req2 + 
 "\n\nCourse 3: " + Coll3 + ": " + Course3 + "\nDecision: " + Decision3 + 
 "\nRequirement: " + Req3 + 
 "\n\nCourse 4: " + Coll4 + ": " + Course4 + "\nDecision: " + Decision4 + 
 "\nRequirement: " + Req4 + 

 "\n\n\nPlease allow 3-4 business days for processing.  If after 3-4 business days, your undergraduate degree audit does not reflect these substitutions, please contact the Office of the University Registrar at registrar@brandeis.edu or 781-736-2010." + 

 MailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, Subject, Message);



}
```

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why a version of this script works perfectly well with a different form, but won't work for me now. I'm relatively new to writing Google scripts, so any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.